# Haskell concurrency over kqueue

Tags: haskell, concurrency, epoll, kqueue

I wrote concurrent application and have caught the error:

> buildFdSets: file descriptor out of range

I found out that it is the OS limit on the number of file descriptors in one process, in my *FreeBSD* it is `1024`. It is the limit of `select()`.  Also I have learned that there is another approach: `kqueue()`.

My questions are:

- How  to win limit on file descriptors?
- How to use `kqueue()` instead of `select()` in haskell programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that GHC 7 now has support for using kqueue() in it's back end:

[link to paper](http://blog.johantibell.com/2010/09/final-version-of-our-ghc-io-manager.html), 
[descriptive blog post](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2010/01/22/new-ghc-io-manager-first-benchmark-numbers/)

However the Haskell Platform is not yet out for GHC 7.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply upgrade to GHC 7, which is part of [the Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform), which [includes](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.general/18297):

> On POSIX platforms, there is a new I/O manager based on epoll/kqueue/poll, which allows multithreaded I/O code to scale to a much larger number (100k+) of threads

In particular:

> Architecturally, our new I/O manager consists of two components. Our event notiﬁcation library provides a clean and portable API,
>   and abstracts the system-level mechanisms used to provide efﬁcient
>   event notiﬁcations (kqueue, epoll, and poll). We have also written a shim that implements the semi-public threadWaitRead and
>   threadWaitWrite interfaces. This means that neither the core ﬁle
>   or networking libraries, nor other low-level I/O libraries, require
>   any changes to work with—and transparently beneﬁt from the performance improvements of—our new code.

That is, just upgrade, and things work magically better.

Here's some reading material:

- [Scalable Event Handling for GHC](http://johantibell.com/files/hask17ape-sullivan.pdf)
- [Scalable timeout support for GHC's I/O manager](http://blog.johantibell.com/2010/01/scalable-timeout-support-for-ghcs-io.html)
- [Playing with the new Haskell epoll event library](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/playing-with-the-new-haskell-epoll-event-library/)